# Pandas: Combine two string columns in dataframe by filling forward certain value

Tags: python, string, pandas, function, dataframe

I have this `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Type': ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue'],
  'V1': ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'],
  'V2': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'],
  'V3': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'],
  'V4': ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes']
})
```

And I want a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Type    V1    V2    V3    V4   V3_4 
0   red     No    Yes   Yes   No   Yes
1   blue    No    Yes   No    No   No
2   red     No    No    No    No   No
3   red     Yes   Yes   Yes   Yes  Yes
4   blue    No    No    No    Yes  Yes
```

So basically any "Yes" values from `V3` are carried forward into a new column `V3_4` as well as "Yes" values from `V4` into column `V3_4`.

It looks like I can do this either with a ffill or build a python function with some logic. I would be fine with either method and am wondering what the most elegant is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [**`np.where`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['V3_4'] = np.where(df.V3.eq('Yes') | df.V4.eq('Yes'), 'Yes', 'No')

   Type   V1   V2   V3   V4 V3_4
0   red   No  Yes  Yes   No  Yes
1  blue   No  Yes   No   No   No
2   red   No   No   No   No   No
3   red  Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes
4  blue   No   No   No  Yes  Yes
```

Thanks to @Anton vBR, this can also be written a bit more concisely:

```
np.where((df1[['V3','V4']].eq('Yes')).any(1), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: great! This worked well. I can accept it in 8 minutes :)

Comment: This is elegant I think, would probably have written it as `np.where((df1[['V3','V4']] == 'Yes').any(1), 'Yes', 'No')`

Comment: I'll add that to the answer, I like that as well

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['red','blue','red','red','blue'], 'V1':['No','No','No','Yes','No'], 'V2':['Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No'], 'V3':['Yes','No','No','Yes','No'], 'V4':['No','No','No','Yes','Yes']})
df1["V3_4"] = np.where(df1["V3"] == "No", df1["V4"], df1["V3"])
print(df1)
```

**Output:**

```
   Type   V1   V2   V3   V4 V3_4
0   red   No  Yes  Yes   No  Yes
1  blue   No  Yes   No   No   No
2   red   No   No   No   No   No
3   red  Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes
4  blue   No   No   No  Yes  Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def build(a,b):
    if a =='Yes':
        return "Yes"
    elif b =='Yes':
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"

df1['V3_4'] = df1[['V3','V4']].apply(lambda x : build(x),axis =1)
```

Comment: Cut out the second and third check, have your else condition return `b`

Comment: Sure, but try to avoid apply when you can!

Answer (score 0):

It may seems trivial but we can replace 'Yes' to True and perform or operation

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['red','blue','red','red','blue'], 'V1':['No','No','No','Yes','No'], 'V2':['Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No'], 'V3':['Yes','No','No','Yes','No'], 'V4':['No','No','No','Yes','Yes']})

df1[['V3','V4']]=df1[['V3','V4']].replace({'Yes':True,'No':False})
x=df1.V4.astype('bool')|df1.V3.astype('bool')

df1[['V3','V4']]=df1[['V3','V4']].replace({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
df1['V3_4']=x.replace({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
df1
```